# How do I control multiply-nested embedding of my iframe?

Tags: content-security-policy, iframe

Domain *example1.com* embeds my iframe.

Domain *example2.com* embeds an iframe served from *example1.com*.

I would set `X-Frame-Options: ALLOW FROM *.example1.com` as well as  `Content-Security-Policy` with `frame-ancestors`.

But then the browser does not allow showing the iframe content, because the window's domain is *example2.com*  which  does not equal *example1.com*.

How can I require whitelisting for the embedder (*example1.com*) and also for the embedder's embedder (*example2.com*)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**CSP `frame-ancestors` already does what you want.**

- `Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors [...]` checks the *entire* ancestor chain. If any parent document doesn't match the source whitelist, your document will not be loaded.

  If your chain is `top(child(grandchild))`, this policy for `grandchild` would pass:

  ```
  Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors top child
  ```

  But none of these:

  ```
   Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors top
   Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors child
   Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'none'
  ```
- `X-Frame-Options: allow-from [...]` only checks a single ancestor. The de-facto implementation in most browsers is that it checks the *top* origin but no origins in between.

  If your chain is `top(child(grandchild))`, this directive for `grandchild` would work:

  ```
  X-Frame-Options: allow-from http://top/
  ```

  But none of these:

  ```
  X-Frame-Options: allow-from http://child/
  X-Frame-Options: sameorigin
  X-Frame-Options: deny
  ```

The W3C CSP2 specification also explains the difference:

> **7.7.1. Relation to X-Frame-Options**
>
> This directive is similar to the `X-Frame-Options` header that several user agents have implemented. The `'none'` source expression is roughly equivalent to that header’s `DENY`, `'self'` to `SAMEORIGIN`, and so on. The major difference is that many user agents implement `SAMEORIGIN` such that it only matches against the top-level document’s location. This directive checks each ancestor. If any ancestor doesn’t match, the load is cancelled. [[RFC7034]](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP2/#biblio-rfc7034)

[(Source)](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP2/#frame-ancestors-and-frame-options)

Comment: Is there a way to allow _any_ top-level ancestors as long as the immediate ancestor of iframe for `domain` is `child`? I don't think the current `frame-ancestors` spec supports that, right?